# setting Multiple alarms in different activities

Tags: android, android-alarms

I am newbie programmer, I am creating an alarm app containing multiple activities, each capable of setting 1 alarm.
I am using same alarm broadcastreciever for all the activities and I use notification manager inside the broadcast reciever.
I pass different ids for different activities that use the broadcastreceiver for notify command using getextras.
 When I try out the application, the alarm which gets shown seems to  be  of the activity whose button i pressed the latest. Also there is a +-1 min error between set time and notification time .Can anyone suggest any other change I can make so I can get multiple notification instead of just one and at the exact set time. Thanks in advance for the answer. :)

here is the alarm receiver code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Toast.makeText
            (context, R.string.app_name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        String Title=intent.getStringExtra("title");
        String days=intent.getStringExtra("days");
        int id=intent.getIntExtra("id", 0);
         NotificationManager nm=(NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Notification notify = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,days,System.currentTimeMillis());
           // Intent i= new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
            PendingIntent p= PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);
            notify.setLatestEventInfo(context, Title, days, p);
            nm.notify(id,notify);
```

Here is the `main.java` code inside `onclicklistener`:

```
           AlarmManager am = null;

            PendingIntent appIntent = null;
            String days = et.getText().toString();
            int daynum = java.lang.Integer.parseInt(days);
            String s2 = (String) ss.getSelectedItem();
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar c1=Calendar.getInstance();
            int y = 2013, m = Calendar.NOVEMBER, d = 29, h = 11, i = 6;
            if (s2.equals("Morning")) {
                h = 7;
            } else if (s2.equals("Afternoon")) {
                h = 12;
            } else if (s2.equals("Evening")) {
                h = 17;
            } else if (s2.equals("Night")) {
                h = 21;
            }
            h=12;i=6;
            c.set(y, m, d, h, i,0);
        c1.setTimeInMillis(c.getTimeInMillis()-daynum*24*60*60*1000);
            button.setText(c1.toString());
            Context context =main.this;
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver2.class);
            intent.putExtra("title", "title");
            intent.putExtra("days",days+" days left");
            intent.putExtra("id",1);
            appIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    intent, 0);
            am = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
            am.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, c.getTimeInMillis(), appIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have multiple alarms you have to create multiple PendingIntent. As from your code you can see that you have passed tha same REQUEST_CODE value, i.e., 0

```
PendingIntent p= PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,intent,0);
```

So to have multiple alarms you have to differentiate the PendingIntents with different values each time. I always use current time value for that as it is different every time. 
Replace your code like I used below and try again.

```
PendingIntent p= PendingIntent.getActivity(context,System.currentTimeInMillis(),intent,0);
```

Thank you.

Comment: i tried, only 1 notification is appearing.must be some other mistake that i may have made.

Comment: I guess you have triggered your alarm only once. Please update your question with your AlarmManager code.

Comment: It works, i had to change request code of the pending intent in the original activity and not that of the broadcast receiver.